# LINQ to SQL, How to merge multiple IQueryable Lists of different subtype?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Consider the following code

```
IQueryable<FooBar> fooBarQuery = _fooBar;
IQueryable<FooBaz> fooBazQuery = _fooBaz;
IQueryable<IFoo> mergedQuery = _fooBar.Cast<IFoo>().Concat(_fooBaz.Cast<IFoo>());
```

The above will merged the _fooBar and _fooBaz. However, the object type in the merged query list will all change to FooBar. If I flip the concat (_fooBaz concat to _fooBar), the object type will change to FooBaz.

I believe, Due to this Subsequent concat on mergedQuery will throw this error: "Types in Union or Concat have members assigned in different order."

Can anybody help me how to merge multiple IQueryable lists of different subtypes?

Comment: Is my answer correct? Thank you clarify if something is missing

Answer (score 8):

A solution is to use intermediate objects:

```
interface IFoo
{
    int PorpertyA { get; }
    int PorpertyB { get; }
    ...
}

class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    public int PorpertyA { get; set; }
    public int PorpertyB { get; set; }
    ...
}

IQueryable<IFoo> mergedQuery =
    fooBarQuery.Select(x => new FooImpl {
        PropertyA = x.PropertyA,
        PropertyB = x.PropertyB
        ...
    })
    .Union(fooBazQuery.Select(x => new FooImpl {
        PropertyA = x.PropertyA,
        PropertyB = x.PropertyB
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Hi I am sorry but your answer did not solve my solution. As I need my objects to be preserved as its concrete object.

Comment: What do you mean by concrete object? Your data is stored in SQL Server, EF (or linq2sql) constructs objects from these data. How these objects are they more concrete than those built in the code above? What is the feature that could not, according to you, be implemented by a class like the FooImpl above?

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided itself merge the two IQueryable lists of different subtypes. May be I don't understand the problem statement correctly. I have used the following code.

```
        List<FooBar> lstFooBar = new List<FooBar>() { new FooBar() { r = 1 } };
        List<FooBaz> lstFooBaz = new List<FooBaz>() { new FooBaz() { z = 2 } };

        IQueryable<FooBar> fooBarQuery = lstFooBar.AsQueryable<FooBar>();
        IQueryable<FooBaz> fooBazQuery = lstFooBaz.AsQueryable<FooBaz>();

        IQueryable<IFoo> mergedQuery = fooBazQuery.Cast<IFoo>  
                                       ().Concat(fooBarQuery.Cast<IFoo>());
```

Where the classes implementation was as follows:

```
 interface IFoo
  {
    int A { get; set; }
   }

class FooBar : IFoo
{
    public int r { get; set; }
    public int A { get; set; }
}

class FooBaz : IFoo
{
    public int z { get; set; }
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

See in the following attachment the two members of the merged query are of different type , not of same type. If there is any understanding issue then please let me know.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1):

Ether I do not understand your problem, or this.

```
IQueryable<FooBar> fooBarQuery = _fooBar;
IQueryable<FooBaz> fooBazQuery = _fooBaz;
IQueryable<IFoo> mergedQuery = _fooBar.Cast<IFoo>().Concat(_fooBaz.Cast<IFoo>()).As<IFoo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
    List<FooBar> list = new List<FooBar> 
    {
        new FooBar{ r=1},
        new FooBar{ r=2},
        new FooBar{ r=3},
    };
    List<FooBaz> list2 = new List<FooBaz> 
    {
        new FooBaz{ z=4},
        new FooBaz{ z=5},
        new FooBaz{ z=6},
    };
    IQueryable<IFoo> fooBarQuery = list.AsQueryable();
    IQueryable<IFoo> fooBazQuery = list2.AsQueryable();
    IQueryable<IFoo> mergedQuery = fooBarQuery.Concat(fooBazQuery);
    foreach (var obj in mergedQuery)
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
}

interface IFoo
{ }

class FooBar:IFoo {
    public int r { get; set; }
}

class FooBaz : IFoo
{
    public int z { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I meant for linq to sql.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to use a common base class instead of an interface. Implemented this way all entities would already be in the same set, so you wouldn't have to merge them.

```
class FooBase
{
    // ...
}

class FooBar : FooBase
{
    // ...
}

class FooBaz : FooBase
{
    // ...
}
```

To separate the different sub types in the FooBase set use [OfType<T>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
IQueryable<FooBase> everything;
IQueryable<FooBar> onlyFooBars = everything.OfType<FooBar>();
```